# Mysql query from three tables based on date

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get user information based on their subscription startdate in MYSQL.

This is what i've come up with this far..

```
    SELECT a.id, a.user_login, a.user_email, c.cardtype, c.accountnumber, a.user_pass, a.user_registered
    FROM users a
    INNER JOIN memberships_users b
    ON b.user_id = a.id
    INNER JOIN memberships_order c
    ON c.user_id = a.id
    WHERE b.status = 'active' AND 
          (c.cyckle_period = 6 AND 
          ('2016-06-01 00:00:00' < (SELECT c.startdate ORDER BY c.startdate DESC LIMIT 1)) 
          OR 
          (c.cyckle_period = 1 AND 
          ('2015-12-01 00:00:00' < (SELECT c.startdate ORDER BY c.startdate DESC LIMIT 1));
```

This query gives me error message "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 8".

Comment: where is it? don't see any `LIMIT 0, 30`

Comment: It's not in the query. I think it's because of the paginate in phpmyadmin.

Comment: There's no 'LIMIT 0, 30' in the code example you posted. The problem might be a simple as a missing space in your syntax but without seeing it in full we can't answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any `LIMIT 0, 30` in your posted code. did you post the right code? BTW, your this below part is totally wrong

```
'2015-12-01 00:00:00' < (SELECT c.startdate ORDER BY c.startdate DESC LIMIT 1)
```

It should rather be

```
'2015-12-01 00:00:00' < SELECT max(startdate) FROM memberships_order
```

Change your `WHERE` part like below

```
WHERE b.status = 'active' AND 
      c.cyckle_period IN (6, 1) AND 
      '2015-12-01 00:00:00' < (SELECT max(startdate) FROM memberships_order);
```

Comment: Like I said, LIMIT 0, 30 is not in the code. PhpMyAdmin adds it after the query. I tried your changes but it game an error for the changes.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT max(startdate) FROM memberships_order) OR (c.cyckle_p' at line 7

Comment: @mattesj, you need to parenthesize the `SELECT`. see edit in answer if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing right parenthesis. According to me it should be,

SELECT a.id, a.user_login, a.user_email, c.cardtype, c.accountnumber, a.user_pass, a.user_registered
    FROM users a
    INNER JOIN memberships_users b
    ON b.user_id = a.id
    INNER JOIN memberships_order c
    ON c.user_id = a.id
    WHERE b.status = 'active' AND 
          (c.cyckle_period = 6 AND 
          ('2016-06-01 00:00:00' < (SELECT c.startdate ORDER BY c.startdate DESC LIMIT 1))) 
          OR 
          (c.cyckle_period = 1 AND 
          ('2015-12-01 00:00:00' < (SELECT c.startdate ORDER BY c.startdate DESC LIMIT 1)));